# Ionic 4 android back button not working

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'm using ionic 4 beta to build an Android app. I'm using angular route for navigation. But my problem is when I build this app for Android and run on my physical device, the android hardware back button not working. I also used ion-back-button with defaulthref attribute but it still not working. But when I click on app back button, it's working but not android back button.

Any idea or solution appreciate.

Comment: Please share what you have done, it will help to find the solution